# Why users are receiving Access Denied error after uploading a file and filling out the metadata

Tags: permissions, access-denied

I have a SharePoint group "Legal contributor". This group has contribute (without delete) rights to the library, and Read access to the site.

Why are users from this group receiving Access Denied error after uploading a file and filling out the metadata?

PS: Major version is enabled.

Comment: Does the file make it to the library? What page are they trying to view after the upload is complete, perhaps its trying to redirect them to a page they don't have access to?

Comment: Yes, file makes to the library and metadata applied. Could it be versioning is enabled and user don't have delete permission?

Comment: Users shouldn't need delete permission to add a file. If the site owner uploads a file, what is the behavior? After they upload a file successfully, what page do they wind up on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when I provided contribute with delete then the error went away. This is due to versioning was enabled and user needs enough right to delete the old version and replace it with the new one.